# How to get access to this class member from within a callback?

Tags: javascript, class, class-members

This question is best explained with some code, so here it is:

```
// a class
function a_class {
    this.a_var      = null;
    this.a_function = a_class_a_function;
}

// a_class::a_function
function a_class_a_function() {
    AFunctionThatTakesACallback(function() {
        // How to access this.a_var?
    });
}

// An instance
var instance = new a_class();
instance.a_function();
```

From within the callback in `AFunctionThatTakesACallback()`, how does one access `this.a_var`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to expand the scope of `this` by creating a local variable that references it, like this:

```
function a_class_a_function() {
   var self = this;
   AFunctionThatTakesACallback(function() {
      console.log(self.a_var); 
   });
}
```

The reason why you need to do this is because the `this` reference within the `AFunctionThatTakesACallback` function is not the same `this` as the current object, it will likely reference the global `window`object instead. (usually not what you want).

Oh, did I mention that this is called a [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)?

Comment: Perfect. That works just fine... and you did a great job of explaining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method of function objects, which lets you specify a value for this:

```
myFunction.call(this, args...)
```

But I think that in this case it would probably be more straightforward to pass 'this' in as one of the parameters to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `instance.a_function()`, you're really calling `a_class_a_function` with `instance` as `this`, so you can modify `a_class_a_function` like so:

```
function a_class_a_function() {
    var self = this;
    AFunctionThatTakesACallback(function() {
        // do something with self.a_var
    });
}
```

The problem here is that if you attempt to call `a_class_a_function` without calling it from an instance, then `this` will likely refer to the global object, `window`.